# Does the Android specification include minimum sensor parameters?

Tags: hardware, sensors

Android apps can access sensor data.  How do I know how accurate the sensor readings are?  Is there a universal standard that specifies operational parameters of a sensor?

E.g., a temperature sensor on an Android device must be able to accurately read temperature with an accuracy of 0.01C over a temperature range from 0C through 100C.

If there is such a standard, is it available for reference online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has an Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD) (see http://source.android.com/compatibility/overview.html) that specifies the minimum (and suggested guidelines) for what a device must physically support to be allowed to use the Android branding (and to get the Google Market and Google's android apps).

The [latest CCD](http://source.android.com/compatibility/2.3/android-2.3.3-cdd.pdf) in section 7.3 lists the minimum requirements of the sensors.  The temperature sensor (section 7.3.7) is actually listed as something that Android devices should *not* include.  There are not specs for this sensor's sensitivity.